# SQL Server varchar conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bumped into an issue.

SQL query

```
INSERT INTO LogItems (Date, Type, UserID, UserName, RefID, Param, OldVal, NewVal) 
VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'Discount', '0', '24.19')
, (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'CM applied', 0, 1)
```

getting message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '24.19' to data type int.

The problem is that columns OldVal and NewVal store all kinds of data/numbers/text and is set to varchar(300).

Why is it trying to convert into 'int' if the filed is set as 'varchar'?

Thank you!

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  24.19 is not an integer.  Why are you trying to insert it into an integer column?

Comment: Numerical values don't go inside single quotes (`'`). `24.19` *can* be implicitly converted to an `int`, `'24.19'` however **cannot**.

Comment: *"The problem is that columns OldVal and NewVal store all kinds of data/numbers/text and is set to varchar(300)."* That is a design flaw unto itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its not an integer column, its a varchar(300), thats what makes this an interesting question. Here's a SQLFiddle of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd7fe8/1

Comment: @MaxCB . . . Your question is even more baffling if the data is supposedly coming from another table, because that is not what this question is asking.

Comment: Anyone who thinks this is a trivial type conversion error, see this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd7fe8/1

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in your `VALUES` table construct you have varying data in your rows. if we add some formatting, this becomes quickly apparent:

```sql
INSERT INTO LogItems (Date, Type, UserID, UserName, RefID, Param, OldVal, NewVal)
VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'Discount',  '0', '24.19'),
       (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'CM applied', 0 , 1);
```

Notice that the 2 last columns have different data types, the first has 2 `varchar` values (that are clearly numerical and thus should not be inside single quotes (`'`)), and the latter are both `int` values.

As you have different data types, and a column must be made up of the same data types through out, then values of a lower data type precedence are converted to the type with the highest. `varchar` has one of the lowest, and so the values `'0'` and `'24.19'` are implicitly converted to `int`s. For `'0'` that's fine, it's an `int` as well, however, the **`varchar`** representing the numerical value `24.19` *cannot*, hence the error.

If you don't wrap the values in single quotes, this will work, and the `1` will be implicitly converted to a `decimal(4,2)`.

Of course, the real problem is this:

> The problem is that columns OldVal and NewVal store all kinds of data/numbers/text and is set to varchar(300).

That is a significant design flaw; fix that. A column can only be made up of one data type, and storing data that isn't meant to be in a `varchar` as a `varchar` will never work out well. [varchar is NOT a one size fits all data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/).

I would personally suggest storing the old row as a whole, not just the column that changed, along with the meta data you need. Then everything is store as it should be, and the "new" row is available in the original table. Especially as a solution like what you have will fall over the moment you update 2 or more columns at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This surprised me, and I've been doing SQL Server for years. [Larnu has already answered very well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66677875/22194) but I feel like I can add something.

The surprise here is that although you are inserting a mixed bag of values into a varchar column, instead of implicitly converting them to varchar, SQL Server is deciding to implicitly convert them to int. This happens because there is an int in the list, and it has higher data type precedence, so SQL Server tries to cast everything to that type. If you were just inserting one row at a time, it would be fine. But because you are inserting two rows, SQL Server implictly invents a table structure for them, without checking what you actually want to do with them. From where I'm sitting, this does look kindof dumb on SQL Servers part. I'm sure it has its reasons.

I could say how you could design everything differently blah blah but sometimes people don't have that choice, so I'll try and solve your immediate problem.

You can force the cast to be made to varchar instead of int by wrapping all the values in an explicit CAST statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO LogItems (Date, Type, UserID, UserName, RefID, Param, OldVal, NewVal) 
VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'Discount', Cast('0' as varchar(300)), Cast('24.19' as varchar(300)))
, (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'CM applied', Cast(0 as varchar(300)), Cast(1 as varchar(300)));
```

This may look crazy but if for example your INSERT statements were being generated in code, this is how to generate them and make the casting happen the way you want it to.

Here's a SQL Fiddle of the problem, which throws an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd7fe8/1

Here's a SQL Fiddle of my solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd7fe8/4

Comment: `your INSERT statements were being generated in code` is *also* a design flaw, as it causes SQL injection, and syntax and runtime errors such as this. Had this been parameterized you wouldn't have had a problem either.

Comment: Design flaws are _always_ debatable, I just wanted to solve the (genuinely interesting) problem presented.

Comment: SQL injection isn't, I'm afraid. There's pages and pages of it on [so] already. I agree with you that the problem is non-obvious

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your kind comments!

To answer some of the concerns, I did not do parameterized because all data is tightly (!) validated.
I wish I could use multiple columns for each data type, or write old/new rows, the constrain is that this is log table that logs historical changes to all the fields on different pages, and users can change them multiple times! 0 and 1 I had as kinda switch (yes/no) flag when user completes certain action. Everything is logged.

And yes, when I put in quotes '0' and '1' and went through. Thank you Larnu and Codeulike for the answer and the feedback!

I felt it is weird that SQL is fine with 'xxxx' and 1 on separate queries but not fine when those values are passed in one query.

`INSERT INTO LogItems (Date, Type, UserID, UserName, RefID, Param, OldVal, NewVal) VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'Discount',  '0', '24.19'), (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '17', '31', 'Nick', '1029', 'CM applied', '0' , '1');`

Comment: Yes you have stumbled upon some surprising behaviour with your example.
Thanks for the thanks.
You've added this reply as a new answer - so the mods will probably come along and tidy it away at some point, its one of the many frowned upon things here, try not to take it personally. Its OK to leave comments on questions or answers though (once you've got enough rep)